# Why does $F(X)$ divide $F'(X)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\Bbb K$ be a field of characteristic zero or a finite field, let $F(X) \in \Bbb K[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial, and let $F(X)= \prod_{i=1}^n(X-x_i)$ be its decomposition in an extension $\Bbb K'$ of $\Bbb K$. Prove that the $n$ roots are all distinct.

The proof in the book reads: "If not, $F(X)$ has a root in common with its derivative $F'(X)$. Therefore, $F(X)$ divides $F'(X)$". The proof is very clear afterwards, but why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $a \in K'$ a common root of $F, F'$. Since $F$ is irreducible, it is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$. Since $F'(a)=0$, you must have that $F$ divides $F'$ (it is a property of the minimal polynomial).

Comment: But that is impossible for degree reasons, except if $F'(X)=0$ (which implies K has positive characteristic).

Comment: The other two answers go the usual gcd route, but this answer addresses OP's question head-on: if $F$ is $a$'s minpoly then it divides any polynomial vanishing at $a$. @Bernard that's exactly the point - the argument the OP quoted is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @whacka: But it's not complete: $F(X)$ *can*  divide $F'(X)$ if the latter is $0$. hen one has to say why it's incompatible with $F$ being irreducible. Note alos it's more a proof by contraposition than by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial $F$ has multiple roots if and only if $\gcd(F,F')$ is not $1$. Since $F$ is irreducible and the gcd can be computed in $K$, the gcd has to be $F$ or $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If, say,  $x_2= x_1$, then $F(X)=(X-x_1)^2G(X)$  and $$F'(X)=2(X-x_1)G(X)+(X-x_1)^2G'(X),$$
hence $F'(x_1)=0=F(x_1)$.

It is well known that `$F$ has no multiple root` is equivalent to `$F(X)$ and $F'(x)$ are coprime`.